# TouchesEnded detected, but not touchesBegan

Tags: ios, uiactionsheet

I am using the calendar view from the Tapku Library (https://github.com/devinross/tapkulibrary) and embedding it into a UIActionSheet - an alternative to the existing UIDatePicker.

The trouble I'm having is when the selected month spans 6 weeks, the bottom row does not pick up any touches from `touchesBegan`, but picks them up in `touchesEnded` and `touchesMoved`.

[May 2013 - 5 weeks http://imageshack.us/a/img62/6280/iossimulatorscreenshot2.png](http://imageshack.us/a/img62/6280/iossimulatorscreenshot2.png)
[June 2013 - 6 weeks http://imageshack.us/a/img41/6280/iossimulatorscreenshot2.png](http://imageshack.us/a/img41/6280/iossimulatorscreenshot2.png)
So in the above screenshots the row starting with June 30 does not get any touches unless they originate somewhere above that row, and then move into it.

I think somewhere the boundaries or frames are incorrectly set, I tried outputting some information about the touch I receive in `touchesEnded` over that last row and get:

```
$0 = 0x1f869670 <UITouch: 0x1f869670> phase: Ended tap count: 1 
window: <_UIAlertOverlayWindow: 0x1e56b1e0; frame = (0 0; 320 568); layer = <UIWindowLayer: 0x1e56b300>> 
view: <TKCalendarMonthTiles: 0x1f86b6d0; 
frame = (0 1; 320 265); layer = <CALayer: 0x1f872fb0>> 
location in window: {67, 551.5} previous location in window: {67, 550} 
location in view: {67, 247.5} previous location in view: {67, 246}
```

The frame of the target view looks correct, what else could be missing?

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, it was the frame of the calendar's superview that was not correctly resizing and caused this inconsistency. The caveat is that since the default `UIView` property `clipsToBounds` is `NO`, views too small to fit their contents will still show the contents, but will not allow user interaction outside of their bounds.